Gaussian integration by parts for $\mathbb{E}[f(B_t) B'_t]$
I am interested in doing a Gaussian integration by parts for an expression of the form
"$\mathbb{E}[f(B_t) B_t'].$"
To make sense of $B'(t)$, I will need the smooth mollified version of the Brownian motion
$$\tilde B_t = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_\epsilon(t-s)B(s) ds$$
and study
$\mathbb{E}[f(\tilde B_t) \tilde B'_t].$
Now, I would like to apply Gaussian integration by parts, and to do this, I would need an isonormal Gaussian process. This is often given by an Ito integral, and we have the standard Gaussian integration by parts
$$\mathbb{E}\Big[f(B_t) \int_0^t g(s) dB_s\Big] = \mathbb{E}\Big[f'(B_t) \int_0^t g(s) ds\Big].$$
Thus, is there a way to write $\tilde B_t$ as an Ito-integral?
Edit: I realized that the above mollification is not quite correct. It would be better to mollify the white noise first and write the new smooth BM as an integral, i.e.
$$\xi^\epsilon_t = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(t-s) \xi(s) ds \quad \text { and  } \qquad  \tilde B_t = \int_{0}^t \xi^\epsilon_s ds.$$

Why do you expect to have a meaningful expression when you know that a Brownian motion is not classically differentiable? Sure it is distributionally differentiable, which means you would need to test the whole expression with smooth enough test function in the time parameter. Sure you can mollify the Brownian motion, but is that what you are really after?

Aha. Now the white noise gets mollified. What is this rigorously? Or better: Highest time to learn Malliavin cakculus from scratch.

Too long for a comment.

Since you mention the isonormal Gaussian process it sounds like you already heard of Malliavin calculus to which this subject belongs.

We know that we cannot just differentiate a Browninan motion $\tilde B_t$ w.r.t. $t\,.$

Your Gaussian integration by parts formula I don't understand.
From ordinary Ito calculus I get


\begin{align}
&f(B_t)\int_0^tg(s)\,dB_s=\int_0^tf(B_s)g(s)\,dB_s+\int_0^t\left(\int_0^sg(u)\,du\right)\,df(B_s)+\left\langle f(B),\int_0^{\,.}g(s)\,dB_s\right\rangle_t\\
\end{align}
and
$$
df(B_t)=f'(B_t)\,dB_t+\frac12 f''(B_t)\,ds\,.
$$
So that
\begin{align}
&f(B_t)\int_0^tg(s)\,dB_s=\int_0^tf(B_s)g(s)\,dB_s+\int_0^t\left(\int_0^sg(u)\,du\right)\,f'(B_s)\,dB_s\\[2mm]&+\frac12\int_0^t\left(\int_0^sg(u)\,du\right)\,f''(B_s)\,ds
+\int_0^tf'(B_s)g(s)\,ds\,.
\end{align}
Taking expectations
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[f(B_t)\int_0^tg(s)\,dB_s\right]=\mathbb E\left[\frac12\int_0^t\left(\int_0^sg(u)\,du\right)\,f''(B_s)\,ds
+\int_0^tf'(B_s)g(s)\,ds\right]\,.
\end{align}

Thanks for the comment! Could you please explain why we can not differentiate the mollified BM $\tilde B_t$? Also, for the integration by parts, I will look at the notes again, I am following the formula $\mathbb{E}[\langle DF, g\rangle] = \mathbb{E}[FW(g)]$ where $D$ is the malliavin deriviation w.r.t. the isonormal Gaussian process $W(g) = \int g dB$, so $Df(B_t) = f'(B_t) \mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}$.

@Xiao we can differentiate a mollified BM $\tilde B_t,.$ What was confusing was your ansatz $\mathbb E[f(B_t)\int_0^tg(s),dB_s],.$ What has that integral to do with $\tilde B_t,?$
